# filterToolbar not working

Tags: jqgrid

Text boxes are appearing below the header but on entering values nothing is happening.
Though after hiting the enter button it shows "loading" sign but no change in the grid.
M using below code for filterToobar. I have written this code just after the definition of jqgrid and inside the $.ready function(everthing else is working fine in my code).
My browser is IE7

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({ 
    url: 'someactionclass'
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "POST",       
    colNames ,
    colModel,
    rowNum:25,
    rowList:[25,50,75,100],
    pager: '#pager',
    sortname: 'rgs_id',
    height: '100%',
    sortorder: "asc", 
    editurl:'someactionclass'
}); 
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false });
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', "#pager",
    { caption: "Toggle", title: "Toggle Search Bar", buttonicon: 'ui-icon-pin-s', 
      onClickButton: function () { $("#list")[0].toggleToolbar() } });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use server side data type: `datatype: "json"`. In the case **the server** is responsible to sorting, paging and filtering of data. The jqGrid just add the filtering parameters as additional parameters and send there to the server.

If you want use local-side sorting, paging and filtering of data you can use `loadonce:true` parameter. In the case you should include the server response the **whole data** (all pages) from the grid. You should understand, that in the case the `datatype` of the grid will be automatically changed from  `datatype: "json"` to  `datatype: "local"` after the first data loading. If you will need reload the data from the server you will have to change the `datatype` back to the original `datatype: "json"` value with respect of `setGridParam` method and then reload the grid.

You should use `gridview:true` jqGrid parameter to improve jqGrid performance. In any way the acceptable performance of local sorting and filtering you can receive only for not so large number of rows. The usage of not large page size (25 rows for example which can be placed on the page without scrolling) can additionally improve the performance.

Comment: @Oleg after adding this code. Its still not working. gridview:true, loadonce:true, loadComplete: function(){ $('#demandsList').setGridParam({datatype: "json"}); $('#demandsList').trigger("reloadGrid"); }

Comment: @Oleg I got filterToolbar working with the help of above added code I wrote the whole code again then It started working but by using "loadonce:true" pagination is not working properly. only first page is getting displayed and there is no option to go to next page but if I remove "loadonce:true" then number of pages are "4" but then filterToolbar is not working.

Comment: @Chhaya: I wrote you that in case of `loadonce:true` usage the server must place in the response **the whole data (all pages)**. I suppose that your server code use `rows` parameter (from the `rowNum`). You should **ignore** the value. Alternative you can use `rowTotal` jqGrid parameter and `totalrows` parameter on the server.

Comment: @Oleg One more doubt. How to use rowTotal to load all the data at once in the grid, "rowTotal: -1" is not working. Is there some default value to fetch all data from database?

Comment: @Chhaya: You can't use negative values for either `rowTotal` or `rowNum`. I think that  "rowTotal: 10000" is large enough. If you have or could have too many rows of data you should never use local side sorting or filtering. You should not forget, that JavaScript in mostly interpreter and work very slow in some browsers IE6-IE8. So in you would implement the sorting, paging and filtering on the server side it will be done **in native code** and so at least 1000 times or much more quickly.

Comment: @Oleg: Hi Oleg, Problem in the filterToolBar. Suppose I enter some value "abc" for the first time its retriving the data, but if I enter "xyz" in another search box and press enter its reloading the entire grid and if I press enter again then its showing the search results, which means that I have to press enter twice to get the results. {searchOnEnter: true/false} not making any difference.